# ssh port forwarding with connection sharing

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I want to create a port forwarding using `ssh`'s `-L` option. The problem I have is that I use connection sharing to the remote host. So depending on if there is already a connection providing a master I either need

```
ssh -O forward -L ... $remotehost
```

(if there is already a master) or

```
ssh -N -L ... $remotehost
```

. I could use something like:

```
if ssh -O check $remotehost 2>/dev/null; then
    ssh -O forward -L ... $remotehost
else
    ssh -N -L ... $remotehost
fi
```

, but this is racy and from C code it would be easier if there was an option that makes `ssh` automatically start a master if there is none yet. For "normal" invocations you could use `-o "ControlMaster auto"`, but this doesn't do the right thing here. I fail to find such an option in the docs however and wonder if I missed something.

So my question is: Is there a catch-all command, that adds a port forward independent of the settings for command multiplexing, that maybe even works if multiplexing isn't enabled at all.

`ssh -N -L ... $remotehost` doesn't seem to do anything at all if an already established connection is used. Is this a bug?

(Of course `ssh -S none -N -L ... $remotehost` works, but the obvious downside is that the maybe already existing connection isn't used then.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was old knowledge, `ssh -N -L ... $remotehost` does the right thing in my setup. Probably fixed since I checked this problem for real last time ... No points for "well researched question" :-)

Checking the changelog of openssh I didn't find this problem mentioned.